# could have only dreamed of/about

Tags: word-choice, word-order

My sentence:

> It is a great chance for every talented child to demonstrate his skills; **the chance which previous generations could have only dreamed of.**

I wonder not only whether the bold part is right, but also about possible alternatives:

> the chance of which previous generations could have only dreamed.
>
> the chance which previous generations could have only dreamed about.
>
> the chance about which previous generations could have only dreamed.

Besides, is the semicolon in the sentence used correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the semi-colon is not correct as it separates a sentence (first part) from a clause (the second). What you require is a comma to separate them.

I would prefer **a chance** to **the chance**. It reads more naturally.

Take your choice between **dreamed of** and **dreamed about**. Both are idiomatic
but **could only have dreamed of/about** flows better than **could have only dreamed of**.

**About which previous generations could only have dreamed** is a bit formal and not a construction that most people would use naturally although perfectly correct.

The quibble you might get is regarding the use of the personal adjective **his** in reference to **child**. Fifty years ago nobody would have noticed. These days the gender generation prefer **their** skills to avoid assuming that the **child** should be male. Or you can opt for the **his or her** formula. This has nothing to do with grammar and everything to do with political correctness.